# Running Clipper under the "dbDOS Pro5 (DosBox)" virtual DOS environment

Tags: dosbox

I am trying to get Clipper to compile small xBase programs in a "dbDOS Pro5 (DosBox)" virtual environment on my Windows 10 computer. The hardware and software is as follows:  CPU: AMD E1-6015 APU, 64-bit, 1.4 GHz / Graphics: Radeon R2 / RAM: 4 GB (3.75 GB usable) / Clipper version: 5.2d.

Clipper starts the compilation process, then stops. The message received is "dbDOS(tm)Pro - Emulator for dbase DOS has stopped working....."

It is interesting that the .EXE files from pre-compiled Clipper programs work very well under the same virtual environment, but Clipper itself does not work, so I cannot generate new compiled .exe files.

Any help would be gratefully acknowledged.

Thank you.....

Answer (score 0):

Why use dbDOS Pro5 instead of DOSBox? dbDOS is mainly an (real) outdated DOSBox mod with a rather useless frontend. Most significant addition to DOSBox is dbDOS’ registration scheme. For instance, the difference with version 4(N) is the version number itself and a change in the registration scheme.

You can await something like dbDOS Pro6+ that will set you back a further $ 149,00. Whoopee, a new version, supported by dbDOS!

Just use original DOSBox.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks for the suggestion.....

Comment: Actual programming in xBase/DOS under Windows seems obsolete. Did you have a look at Harbour, https://harbour.github.io? That at least compiles your Clipper programs with little fuss or adjustments to genuine Windows programs.

For running existing DOS programs, you could also try vDos, https://vdos.info. That probably would do a better job than dbDOS/DOSBox since it specializes in “serious” DOS programs.

Comment: Incidentally, your earlier suggestion for using the original DOSBox has worked out very well. I've got my Clipper systems up and running. Thanks, again. I have not looked at Harbor. For now, I am content with DosBox because I am back in business (with Clipper/DOS) on my Win10 computer. At some point in time, I will have to check out the full dBASE for Win10, and migrate there.....